# Deploy changes to Django 1.3 code onto Amazon EC2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2

I'm still trying to figure out EC2 hosting. I had my small site up and then I made changes. I SSH'd my way in, cut the server (CRTL C), screen -R and then did git pull. Now how do I restart the process again?

Thanks for helping out a noob.

Comment: Please tell me that you're [not running the Django development server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port) `./manage.py runserver`.

Comment: If you are, please stop and install Django into Apache or nginx or whatever web server you'll be using.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://sam.odio.com/blog/labels/linux%20debian%20lighttpd%20django%20python.html - does this help in answering my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

After git pull, I need to run:

```
python manage.py runfcgi method=prefork host=127.0.0.1 port=9090 pidfile=django.pid
```

Then exit:

```
Ctrl + a d
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the way to start Apache would be to run `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` or `/etc/init.d/httpd start`.